# Reorder adjacent rows (higher/lower) before insert/update, using trigger

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, triggers

Given the following table `books`

```
 id | listorder 
----+-----------
  3 |         1
  2 |         2
  1 |         3
  4 |         4
  6 |         5
  7 |         6
  5 |         7
```

I can update the row where id=3 to listorder=6 by executing the following, which first re-orders the adjacent rows before updating the new position:

```
UPDATE books
SET listorder = listorder - 1
WHERE listorder <= 6 -- The new position
  AND listorder > (SELECT listorder 
                   FROM books WHERE id = 3);

UPDATE books
SET listorder = 6 -- The new position
WHERE id = 3;
```

How can I create a trigger function that will run **before** UPDATE or INSERT, so that all I need to do is update the listorder, and the other rows will re-order beforehand automatically, **regardless** of whether moving higher or lower in the listorder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to prevent recursive triggering. Use [`pg_trigger_depth()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-info.html) function to ensure that the function is triggered only once per user's `insert` or `update`.

**Table**

```
create table books (id int, listorder int);
insert into books values
(3, 1),
(2, 2),
(1, 3),
(4, 4),
(6, 5),
(7, 6),
(5, 7);
```

**Trigger**

```
create or replace function books_trigger()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
    if tg_op = 'UPDATE' then
        if new.listorder > old.listorder then
            update books
            set listorder = listorder- 1
            where listorder <= new.listorder
            and listorder > old.listorder
            and id <> new.id;
        else
            update books
            set listorder = listorder+ 1
            where listorder >= new.listorder
            and listorder < old.listorder
            and id <> new.id;
        end if;
    else
        update books
        set listorder = listorder+ 1
        where listorder >= new.listorder
        and id <> new.id;
    end if;
    return new;
end $$;

create trigger books_trigger
before insert or update on books
for each row when (pg_trigger_depth() = 0)
execute procedure books_trigger();
```

**Tests**

*Insert*

```
insert into books values (8, 5);
table books order by 2;

 id | listorder
----+-----------
  3 |         1
  2 |         2
  1 |         3
  4 |         4
  8 |         5
  6 |         6
  7 |         7
  5 |         8
(8 rows)
```

*Update*

```
update books set listorder = 2 where id = 8;
table books order by 2;

 id | listorder
----+-----------
  3 |         1
  8 |         2
  2 |         3
  1 |         4
  4 |         5
  6 |         6
  7 |         7
  5 |         8
(8 rows)

update books set listorder = 4 where id = 8;
table books order by 2;

 id | listorder
----+-----------
  3 |         1
  2 |         2
  1 |         3
  8 |         4
  4 |         5
  6 |         6
  7 |         7
  5 |         8
(8 rows)
```

The trigger works well on a multiple rows insert with the same `listorder`:

```
insert into books values (9, 4), (10, 4), (11, 4), (12, 4);
table books order by 2;

 id | listorder
----+-----------
  3 |         1
  2 |         2
  1 |         3
 12 |         4
 11 |         5
 10 |         6
  9 |         7
  8 |         8
  4 |         9
  6 |        10
  7 |        11
  5 |        12
(12 rows)
```

but it does not allow a multiple rows update:

```
update books set listorder = 4
where id > 8;

ERROR:  tuple to be updated was already modified by an operation triggered by the current command
HINT:  Consider using an AFTER trigger instead of a BEFORE trigger to propagate changes to other rows.
```

In the context of preserving the uniqueness of the column `listorder` it is logical and desirable behavior, because a result of this query is ambiguous.

Comment: This is really very useful, klin. Thanks. Is there any way to prevent multiple books being inserted or updated with the same listorder within one operation (automatically increment the listorder, for example)?

Comment: The issue is a bit complicated. I have changed my mind after some extra tests, In some cases a `trigger after` might produce unpredictable results. See the updated answer. Note that the trigger function has changed a little.